# How do you use the Excel function trend?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do you use the Excel function `trend`? How do you fill the condition?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it myself, but two decent resources are:

1. A decent explanation of the parameters, with graphical example:
   http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052093201033.aspx
2. A longer explanation + example (also details changes in behavior between Excel versions, which you may or may not need to know):
   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828801